# How to correctly sort input by average using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Write a function named `sort_by_average_rating` that takes a list/array of key-value stores as a parameter where each key-value store has keys `ratings`, `budget`, and `box_office` where `budget` and `box_office` are integers and `ratings` is a list of integers. Sort the input based on the average of the values in `ratings`.

```
function sort_by_average_rating(lista){
    for (var i of lista){
    lista.sort((a,b)=>(a.ratings.reduce)/(b.ratings.length));
    }
    return lista;
}
```

How can I fix this?

```
function sort_by_average_rating incorrect on input [[{'box_office': 35874798, 'ratings': [5, 2, 3, 9, 5, 2, 9], 'budget': 16277234.16}, {'box_office': 36159718, 'ratings': [9, 8, 2, 10, 6], 'budget': 14928243.11}, {'box_office': 45902132, 'ratings': [7, 7, 6], 'budget': 17305426.77}, {'box_office': 9920255, 'ratings': [8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1], 'budget': 4214447.4}, {'box_office': 28163915, 'ratings': [1, 7, 8, 3, 8], 'budget': 5841329.67}, {'box_office': 5431090, 'ratings': [3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 10], 'budget': 14396357.77}, {'box_office': 29674945, 'ratings': [1, 10, 2, 5], 'budget': 10909102.42}, {'box_office': 30136528, 'ratings': [1, 6, 1, 10], 'budget': 17685214.68}]]

result: [{'box_office': 35874798, 'ratings': [5, 2, 3, 9, 5, 2, 9], 'budget': 16277234.16}, {'box_office': 36159718, 'ratings': [9, 8, 2, 10, 6], 'budget': 14928243.11}, {'box_office': 45902132, 'ratings': [7, 7, 6], 'budget': 17305426.77}, {'box_office': 9920255, 'ratings': [8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1], 'budget': 4214447.4}, {'box_office': 28163915, 'ratings': [1, 7, 8, 3, 8], 'budget': 5841329.67}, {'box_office': 5431090, 'ratings': [3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 10], 'budget': 14396357.77}, {'box_office': 29674945, 'ratings': [1, 10, 2, 5], 'budget': 10909102.42}, {'box_office': 30136528, 'ratings': [1, 6, 1, 10], 'budget': 17685214.68}]

expected: [{'box_office': 5431090, 'ratings': [3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 10], 'budget': 14396357.77}, {'box_office': 29674945, 'ratings': [1, 10, 2, 5], 'budget': 10909102.42}, {'box_office': 30136528, 'ratings': [1, 6, 1, 10], 'budget': 17685214.68}, {'box_office': 35874798, 'ratings': [5, 2, 3, 9, 5, 2, 9], 'budget': 16277234.16}, {'box_office': 9920255, 'ratings': [8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1], 'budget': 4214447.4}, {'box_office': 28163915, 'ratings': [1, 7, 8, 3, 8], 'budget': 5841329.67}, {'box_office': 45902132, 'ratings': [7, 7, 6], 'budget': 17305426.77}, {'box_office': 36159718, 'ratings': [9, 8, 2, 10, 6], 'budget': 14928243.11}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this would work for you:

```js
var data = [{ 'box_office': 35874798, 'ratings': [5, 2, 3, 9, 5, 2, 9], 'budget': 16277234.16 }, { 'box_office': 36159718, 'ratings': [9, 8, 2, 10, 6], 'budget': 14928243.11 }, { 'box_office': 45902132, 'ratings': [7, 7, 6], 'budget': 17305426.77 }, { 'box_office': 9920255, 'ratings': [8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1], 'budget': 4214447.4 }, { 'box_office': 28163915, 'ratings': [1, 7, 8, 3, 8], 'budget': 5841329.67 }, { 'box_office': 5431090, 'ratings': [3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 10], 'budget': 14396357.77 }, { 'box_office': 29674945, 'ratings': [1, 10, 2, 5], 'budget': 10909102.42 }, { 'box_office': 30136528, 'ratings': [1, 6, 1, 10], 'budget': 17685214.68 }]

const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((r,c) => r + c) / arr.length
const result = data.sort((a,b) => avg(a.ratings) - avg(b.ratings))

console.log(result)
```

Using `sort` and then a helper function which via `reduce` adds all the entries and returns the avg.